# Will my old posts show on friend's timelines if I re-activate my Facebook account?

Tags: facebook

If I reactivate my Facebook account after leaving it deactivated for several months, will my posts from several months ago show up on everyone's timeline immediately after I reactivate?

Comment: From my experience, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, if you reactivate your account. All post, comments, information will remain exactly the same as it is when you deactivated your account. Including likes and comments!

I have never deactivated my account so here are the sources:(I'm not very sure about this)

[From StackExchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43476/what-happens-to-my-comments-likes-and-chat-when-i-delete-my-facebook-profile)

[From Facebook](https://m.facebook.com/help/125338004213029?refid=69)

[From Yahoo Answers](https://sg.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091226155501AA9AFif)